# Moving Deja Dup Backups From Dropbox to Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, backup, dropbox, deja-dup

Is there a way where I can instead transfer/upload all my previous Deja dup backups from my Dropbox to my Ubuntu One and then from there, Deja dup will just continue synching with it whenever it performs its scheduled backup operations?

Answer (score 2):

Déjà-Dup saves his files in a normal folder, so I believe that you can do following:

- 1) create a folder on Ubuntu One with the web interface
- 2) upload all your Déjà-dup files (from dropbox) to Ubuntu One in the new folder
- 3) set Déjà-dup client to save the backups on Ubuntu One in the folder you created on step 1

I have not tried this myself but I don't see why this shouldn't work.